# Need help understanding clojure compilation error loading__4958__auto__

Tags: clojure, leiningen

So I run `lein repl` and it complains:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myapp/views/test$loading__4958__auto__, compiling:(web.clj:1:1)
```

I have no idea what this means. It is a simple web project where myapp.web requires a hiccup view from myapp.views.test. If I run `lein ring server` the error instead becomes

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ring/adapter/jetty$loading__4958__auto__, compiling:(ring/server/standalone.clj:1:1)
```

What is that `loading__4958__auto__` stuff and how can I "decipher" these cryptic compile errors? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add to your question your web.clj namespace declaration and the myapp/views/test file?

Comment: and your project.clj dependencies

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, see my new answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried trying to make a minimal reproducible case to attach to my question by commenting out unnecessary stuff. I ran `lein clean` and then `lein ring server` at every step. At one point the app started working again! So then I started to re add all the commented stuff to find the culprit. But I never got the error again, rather I managed to re add everything step by step up to the exact same source code as I started with, and the app is still working. I must have gotten my lein/clojure stuff into a bad state by some renames I did, or something similar.

I wont flag this as the selected answer because it does not actually answer the question, it just happened to start working again. It would be great if someone had more insight into what the `NoClassDefFoundError loading__4958__auto__ error` actually means.